# Python recursive counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I need a recursive counter in python counting from 1 to n.

```
  def countup(n):
       a=1
       def hoch(a,n):
          if a<=n:
             print(a)
             a+=1
             hoch(a,n)
       hoch(a,n)
```

Comment: As someone from Germany you should know the wise words "Wieso einfach, wenn es auch kompliziert geht?" (*Why simple if it can be done complicated?*)

Comment: What's wrong with `for x in range(1,n): print(x)` ? How is this 'recursive' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
def countup(n):
    if n >= 0:
        countup(n - 1)
        print(n)
countup(10)
```

Basically, if the number passed into `countup` is greater than 0, it recursively runs `countup` again, passing into it the next number below.

It only uses 1 function.

P.S. It already existed here:

[python recursive function that prints from 0 to n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127355/python-recursive-function-that-prints-from-0-to-n)

Answer (score 0):

You can do very simple *without* recursion, which is not the ideal way to go.

```
def countup(n):
    print(*range(n + 1), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to do this recursively (which isn't the best way to do it), another option is to pass `a` to `countup()` as an optional argument.

```
def countup(n, a=1):
    if a <= n:
        print(a)
        countup(n, a+1)

countup(10)
```